# Using attached properties in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I am trying to create a Read Only attach property in WPF that will calculate the total Visual Child count of the control. The benefit of this is not important to me, it's being able to use attach properties properly!

Firstly I've declared my property like so:

```
internal static readonly DependencyPropertyKey TotalChildCountPropertyKey =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttachedReadOnly("TotalChildCount", typeof(int), typeof(MyAttachClass), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TotalChildCountProperty = TotalChildCountPropertyKey.DependencyProperty;


    public static int GetTotalChildCount(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (int)obj.GetValue(TotalChildCountProperty);
    }

    public static void SetTotalChildCount(DependencyObject obj, int value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(TotalChildCountPropertyKey, value);
    }
```

I also have a recursive method declared else where like so:

```
public static class Recursive
{
    public static IEnumerable<DependencyObject> GetAllChildren(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        List<DependencyObject> col = new List<DependencyObject>();
        GetAllChildrenImp(obj, col);
        return col;

    }

    private static void GetAllChildrenImp(DependencyObject current,     List<DependencyObject> col)
    {
        if (current != null)
        {
            col.Add(current);

            for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(current); i++ )
            {
                GetAllChildrenImp(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(current, i), col);
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Now I wish to use this method to assign a value to the GetTotalChildCount property, but I cannot figure out the best way of doing. I could add an event handler to the dependency property changes, but this will never fire because I will only be reading from the value in xaml.

Here's how I am using it in xaml:

```
<TextBox DataContext="{RelativeSource Self}" Text="{Binding local:MyAttachClass.TotalChildCount}"></TextBox>
```

So to summarize. I wish to set a DependencyObjects TotalChildCount attach property and then be able to bind to it in xaml. As it stands this is not working, the GetTotalChildCount is not even getting hit.

Oh this is my first question, hopefully I was clear enough

Comment: Do you need to add children to TextBox? I think only Container controls like Grid/StackPanel/DockPanel etc, are allowed to have children.

Comment: I don't need to add child. The GetAllChildren method will return all of the Dependency Objects that make up a TextBox, such as borders etc

Comment: `GetTotalChildCount()` should be called at least once. But if you don't call `SetTotalChildCount()`, it likely would not be called again for a given binding. Unfortunately, without a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces your problem, it's difficult to know exactly what you're trying to do, never mind how to fix the code.

Answer (score -2):

You can try it this way

Attached property

```
public class MyAttachClass
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TotalChildCountProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("TotalChildCount", typeof(int), typeof(MyAttachClass), 
    new PropertyMetadata(-1, OnTotalChildCountChanged));

    public static int GetTotalChildCount(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (int)obj.GetValue(TotalChildCountProperty);
    }

    public static void SetTotalChildCount(DependencyObject obj, int value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(TotalChildCountProperty, value);
    }

    public static void OnTotalChildCountChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox txt = sender as TextBox;
        if (txt != null)
        {
            var children = Recursive.GetAllChildren(txt);
            txt.Text = children.Count().ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

And the xaml as

```
<TextBox local:MyAttachClass.TotalChildCount="0" ></TextBox>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: The OP is implementing a read-only property. The above is not read-only (and to make matters worse, proposes entirely too much coupling to a client element, by hard-coding the property-changed behavior for the client element in the attached property control itself).